# Efficient way to order a dictionary by value and stringify it

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary with string keys and int values

```
for word in coocc[query]:
    resp[word]=coocc[query][word]
```

> {"share": 1, "pizza": 3, "eating": 1,...}

I need to sort by value and return a json string.

The following works:

```
sortedList=sorted(resp.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
sortedDict=collections.OrderedDict(sortedList)
return json.dumps(sortedDict)
```

> '{"cheese": 4, "pizza": 3, "table": 3,..}

but it doesn't seems very efficient to me

Comment: might be easier to read in multiple lines, but that's just about the best you can do really. It's fine.

Comment: Which Python version are you using? CPythpn 3.6+ and PyPy 3 preserve insertion order of dict, meaning you don’t needrthe slightly heavier OrderedDict.

Comment: can you  give an example of your output ?

Comment: python 3.5.4 still requires OrderedDict

Comment: @ParitoshSingh see my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
json.dumps(sorted(yourdict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True))
```

you can find more details 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613218/5277295)

Comment: If you skip the dict step it becomes '[["cheese", 4], ["pizza", 3], ["table", 3],

Comment: i corrected your answer for the specifics of the question

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 solution:

```
d = {"share": 1, "pizza": 3, "eating": 1,"table": 5, "cheese": 4 }
sorted = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
print(sorted)
print (json.dumps(sorted))
```

output:

```
{'share': 1, 'eating': 1, 'pizza': 3, 'cheese': 4, 'table': 5}
{"share": 1, "eating": 1, "pizza": 3, "cheese": 4, "table": 5}
```

EDIT:

```
import json
d = {"share": 1, "pizza": 3, "eating": 1,"table": 5, "cheese": 4 }
sorted = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse = True))
print(sorted)
print (json.dumps(sorted))
```

output:

```
{'table': 5, 'cheese': 4, 'pizza': 3, 'share': 1, 'eating': 1}
{"table": 5, "cheese": 4, "pizza": 3, "share": 1, "eating": 1}
```

Comment: where do you fit the reverse=True?